# How to open csv file? Curvefitter unable to open specified session matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, datatable, curve-fitting

I tried to open a csv file. Its already imported in matlab and I can't save the .m file as .sfit, because that results in .sfit.m file which is the only possibility.
How to proceed?

Would be happy if someone could help me!!

[image]

Comment: as per documentation `curveFitter(filename) loads the Curve Fitter session in filename into the Curve Fitter app. filename must have the extension .sfit.`. There is no workaround, you should then read your .CSV and create a sfit obejct from it and save it to a .SFIT file https://ch.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/sfit.html